# ListView setOnItemClickListener with JSONArray and JSONObject

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a problem with a setOnItemClickListener from a listView.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ItemClick();
            }
        });
```

And ItemClick:

```
private int ItemClick (){
    try {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jo=null;

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String nr_telefon=jo.getString("nr_telefon");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,nr_telefon,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The problem it's that return doesn't work (I think) When I click on a item from listView it's like I clicked on all the items. On click will show me all the toast with the nr_telefon from first item to last one. What's the problem and how to fix it?

And one item from list view it's created like this:

```
 String  nr_masina=jo.getString("nr_masina");
   String proprietar=jo.getString("proprietar");
   String nr_telefon=jo.getString("nr_telefon");
   names.add(nr_masina + "\n" + proprietar + "\n" + nr_telefon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the `ItemClick` method displays the `Toasts` for every item in the `JSONArray`.

Try to add an argument `int position` to the method and pass the position with it:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ItemClick(position);
        }
```

Note that the `for` loop is gone. It used to display a `Toast` for each item in the `JSONArray ja`. Now the logic is invoked only once, for the item with `position` index:

```
    private int ItemClick(int position){
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);

            jo = ja.getJSONObject(position);
            String nr_telefon = jo.getString("nr_telefon");        
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,nr_telefon,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not passing position on the clicked item in the listview. Use this code

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ItemClick(position);
        }
    });
```

And the change method to this

```
private int ItemClick (int pos){
try {
    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
    JSONObject jo=null;


        jo=ja.getJSONObject(pos);
        String nr_telefon=jo.getString("nr_telefon");

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,nr_telefon,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    return 1;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Work's perfect. Thank's you !